How can I use the public folder in a custom npm package build with Vite?
I have a npm package build with Vue 3/Vite, and I have to put my fonts inside a public asset folder so vite can resolve it at build time. This works fine when I build the story book and then I run npm run build.
My issue is: When I'm using this npm package inside my application, I get 404 errors when the application uses a component from that package. When using the paths in .scss for those fonts, my application doesn't find those folders on my public folder. It should be looking for those fonts inside the npm package, but is not.
This is my path in scss: $r-asset-path: '/assets/'. If I change to './assets/', the build will have the error vite can't resolve it at build time.
Is there a way change this path so it can be dynamic, use '/assets/' on building the package but to not use when I'm using inside an application? I can see the assets folder inside dist on node_modules.
This is my vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue' 
const path = require("path")

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      'assets': fileURLToPath(new URL('./assets', import.meta.url)), //trial to see if it works or not
    }
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: { 
         additionalData: `@import "@/styles/__main.scss";` 
      },
    },
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/main.ts"),
      name: "ui-vue3",
      fileName: (format) => `ui-vue3.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
    assetsInlineLimit: 0
  }
})

If there's more code needed please let me know so I can provide it.
Thanks in advance.

"so vite can resolve it at build time" - can you clarify what you mean? public folder is copied to dist/ as is, nothing inside it is supposed to be resolved at build time. " When using the paths in .scss for those fonts, my application doesn't find those folders on my public folder" - please, show what you do and what happens

If I try to build the projec], I get a warning: referenced in (...) didn't resolve at build time... the fonts will converted to base64 and the CSS file gets huge
When I use the custom npm package inside my application, those .scss rules are looking to the public folder on my application instead of the node_modules. I can provide some screenshots if needed

Please, provide code that causes the problem and the exact warnings. Screenshots may be helpful too, but they need to be duped with text for better searchability, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 . "those .scss rules are looking to the public folder" - this looks like a normal thing if I understood your case correctly. If you rely on public/ in lib package, it's expected that it will end up in app's dist/ via copying, you need to handle this. It's not recommended to bundle fonts exactly because they will be "converted to base64 and the CSS file gets huge".
